# html parsing of comments which enclose javascript

Tags: javascript, html

From the SGML/HTML standard:

"To put it simply, the double dash at the start and end of the comment do not start and end the comment. Double dash indicates a change in what the comment is allowed to contain. The first -- starts the comment, and tells the browser that the comment is allowed to contain > characters without ending the comment. The second -- does not end the comment. It tells the browser that if it encounters a > character, it must then end the comment. If another -- is added, then it goes back to allowing the > characters.
"

My question is:

Assuming some javascript is inside a html comment, how would I handle '>' characters in
the script..

for example

```
 <!-- 
 <script>
 for(x=10;x>1;x--) 
  { 
  if(x>5) {}
  }
 </script>
 -->
```

wouldn't the x-- set the html parser to consider the next '>' as the end of the comment,
which in this case would be the greater than sign in the (x>5)  ?

An example causing me more confustion:

```
          <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="/respond.js" >
          var i=10;
          if(i-->5) {}
          </script>-->
          <![endif]-->
```

Comment: You need not handle this. Atleast chrome handles this itself. Try this http://jsbin.com/vasupike/1/edit?html,console,output

Comment: It will be helpful you actually link to the standard link from where you have picked up the excerpt

Answer (score 0):

As per [MDN Documentation on correct use of comments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/The_Importance_of_Correct_HTML_Commenting)

```
[15] Comment ::= '<!--' ((Char - '-') | ('-' (Char - '-')))* '-->'
```

Therefore `-- >` does not end comment block in XML but ends it in HTML.

Example from the same source

#### Valid Comment

```
<!-- valid xml/xhtml comment -->
```

#### Invalid comments

```
<!-- invalid -- xml comment -->
<!-- invalid xml comment --->
<!-- invalid xml comment -- >
```

Now, your question

> wouldn't the x-- set the html parser to consider the next '>' as the end of the comment

**Answer**: NO, html parses considers only `-->` as the end of the comment and not any other combination. Only white space can appear in the end block for HTML parser like `-- >`

Comment: the second example I edited into the question, seems wrong:  http://jsbin.com/vasupike/2/

Comment: @AshodApakian How about commenting in this manner http://jsbin.com/cuhezari/1/edit?html,output

Comment: -writing html code is not my problem... It's developing a parser to handle the comments in html

Comment: @AshodApakian I understand but your parser will have some definite set of rules which can be parsed. So I guess you can consider this as a limitation of existing HTML parser.

Comment: even http://jsbin.com/comol/1/ doesn't recognize the last two lines as comment - anyone explain why ?

Comment: I think touches on this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/js-tools/kBJSzXOwSRU